# byobu: how to change status-line location from 'bottom' to 'top'?

Tags: byobu

What is the idiomatic config to change the status line location from `bottom` to `top`?

I have tried using `set-window-option -g status-position top` (using `tmuxinator`), but as soon as I include that line, all the byobu features are gone and I'm back to standard tmux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I struggled to find any documentation for this too. It turns out you have to modify *byobu's* tmux configuration file - not your local tmux config.

Adding the following worked for me

`~/.byobu/.tmux.conf`

```
# move status bar to the top
set-option -g status-position top
```